# Optimization of perl code for one of the problems?

Tags: perl

Which one of the code will be faster?
I have been trying some of the community website with problems.
For a problem I have submitted two solutions. 
My first solution got accepted yet the other one was rejected.

```
#INPUT consist of two integer ie 5 10 
# 23 200
# Solution 1 (accepted)

@_ = split(/\s/,<>);

if ( $_[0]%5 != 0 ) {
    $_[1] =  sprintf("%.2f",$_[1]);
    print $_[1];
    exit;
} 
if ( $_[0]+0.5 > $_[1]  ) {
    $_[1] =  sprintf("%.2f",$_[1]);
        print $_[1];
        exit;
}

$_[1] = sprintf("%.2f",($_[1] - ($_[0]+.5) ) );
print $_[1];
```

Or

```
#Solution 2 (rejected)

@_ = split(/\s/,<>);

if ( $_[0]%5 != 0 ) {
    print (sprintf("%.2f",$_[1]));
    exit;
} 
if ( $_[0]+0.5 > $_[1]  ) {
    print (sprintf("%.2f",$_[1]));
exit;
}

print (sprintf("%.2f",$_[1]));
```

Comment: If you want to know how fast some code is, then [benchmark](http://modperlbook.org/html/9-2-Perl-Code-Benchmarking.html) it. Don't ask us.

Comment: Don't they teach people how to time code anymore? (Hint: `time`)

Comment: I would not reject code for using `print(sprintf(...))` instead of `printf`, but the temptation would certainly be there.

Comment: @GregHewgill: There's probably not enough going on for `time` to give meaningful data -- and the time spent by `sprintf` and `print` is going to dwarf the time spent doing the computation.

Comment: It is bad enough that the language designers choose to use @_ as the name of the argument list in a function.  Why would anyone use such a name for a variable that could have a reasonable name?

Comment: Besides the obvious problems with your "solutions", they also give different results. You'd probably get much better answers if you just described what you're supposed to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Your second variant is slightly faster, but it would not mean any real difference.

I'd reject both solution due to bad quality of code - you should start naming your variables. Also, learn about elsif/else and use them instead of exit.